# Specifying pronunciations with user dictionaries (Nuance Vocalizer Expressive TTS 5.4)

Tags: dictionary, edit, text-to-speech, voice

I am currently trying to correct pronunciation of a word using dictionary called **userdct_eng.dct** which later will be converted to **.dat** file using python.

My problem is I don't know how to modify the pronunciation of an input word which enclosed in double quotes (").

this is the example code inside the dictionary:

> [Header]
>
> Name=userdct_eng.dct
>
> Description=userdct_eng
>
> Language=ENG
>
> Content=EDCT_CONTENT_BROAD_NARROWS
>
> Representation=EDCT_REPR_SZZ_STRING
>
> [Data]
>
> **you // #'jEs#**
>
> **"you" // #'jEs#**

I am trying to modify word **you** to pronounce as **yes**. it's work, this string ( **you // #'jEs#** ) is working.

And in the second string I am trying to modify word **"you"** (including the double quotes) to pronouncing as **yes**. but it doesn't, this string ( **"you" // #'jEs#** ) doesn't work, the voice still pronounce it as **you**.

my question is: How to deal with double quotation marks word?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED by using backslash (\) before double quote (").
Example:

\"you\" // #'jEs#